# Странная работа gin роутеров

Tags: веб-программирование, golang, веб-сервер, маршрутизация, golang-gin

столкнулся с проблемой "странного" роутинга запросов.

```
func InitRouter() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(gin.Recovery())

    v1 := router.Group("/v1", ResponseWriter, VerifyToken, VerifyUser)
    {
        // domain
        domain := v1.Group("/domain")
        {
            domain.POST("/add",
                AddDomainBind,
                AddDomain)

            domain.DELETE("/:id",
                SetDomainContext,
                VerifyDomainAccess,
                DeleteDomain)

            domain.PUT("/:id/check",
                SetDomainContext,
                VerifyDomainAccess,
                CheckParking)

            domain.GET("",
                BindDomainFilter,
                GetDomainList)
        }

        // admin
        admin := v1.Group("/admin", VerifyAccess([]string{"admin"}))
        {
            // domain
            domain := admin.Group("/domain")
            {
                domain.DELETE("/:id", DeleteDomain)
                domain.GET("/ping", ResultPing)
            }
        }
    }



    if err := router.Run(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", env.Getenv("HTTP_PORT"))); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Странность заключается в том, что при GET запросе по адресу http://localhost:8081/v1/admin/domain/ping я получаю 404

Однако если сделать запрос в группу domain, которая стоит первой перед admin - все без проблем выполняется.

Решил воссоздать тестовый вариант роутинга

```
func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(gin.Recovery())

    v1 := router.Group("/v1")
    {
        // domain
        domain := v1.Group("/domain")
        {
            domain.GET("/ping", ping)
        }


        // admin
        admin := v1.Group("/admin")
        {
            // domain
            domain := admin.Group("/domain")
            {
                domain.GET("/ping", ping)
            }
        }
    }

    router.Run(":8080")
}

func ping(ctx *gin.Context) {
    ctx.JSON(200, nil)
    return
}
```

Во втором варианте такая же конструкция и работает отлично, по GET запросу http://localhost:8080/v1/admin/domain/ping нет никаких ошибок и роутер срабатывает. Вопрос, почему так, что я упустил?

Comment: А вы уверены, что это не `VerifyAccess` вам 404 выдаёт?

Comment: @Ainar-G я пробовал без него, эффект тот же

Comment: А POST /v1/domain/add у вас работает? Есть подозрение, что паттерны `:id` перекрывают действия. Помню такой прикол у gin'а.

Comment: @Ainar-G да, все что касается domain работает, а вот админка не хочет. Пытался сейчас закомментить POST, к сожалению все равно 404